# get data from tyhe back end and update them

Tags: angular, forms, angular-httpclient

hello Im trying to get data from the back end spring boot and update them the method update work on postman but the data not fetch in the form this is my error in console

```
platform-browser.js:745 The specified value "Assaibi" cannot be parsed, or is out of range.
platform-browser.js:745 The specified value "Takwa" cannot be parsed, or is out of range.
.......
```

[image]

and there it return a fake data on the form
this is my edit.ts

```
import { HttpErrorResponse } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { NgForm } from "@angular/forms";
import { PersonService } from "../person.service";
import { Utilisateur } from "../Utilisateur";
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";
@Component({
  selector: "app-edit",
  templateUrl: "./edit.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./edit.component.css"],
})
export class EditComponent implements OnInit {
  public u: Utilisateur;

  constructor(
    private personSer: PersonService,
    private router: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // console.log(this.router.snapshot.params.id);
    console.log(this.personSer.findEmpBy(this.router.snapshot.params.id));
    this.editR(this.router.snapshot.params.id);
  }

  Modifier(Uti: Utilisateur) {
    this.personSer.updateEmp(Uti).subscribe(
      (response: Utilisateur) => {
        this.u = Uti;

        console.log(response);
      },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        alert(error.message);
      }
    );
  }

  editR(e: number) {
    this.personSer.findEmpBy(e).subscribe(
      (response: Utilisateur) => {
        this.u = response;
      },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        alert(error.message);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

this is my edit.html

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<body>
   <div class="container">
      <h1 class="title">Modifier profil</h1>
      <form >
         <div class="grid">
            <div class="form-group a">
               <label for="name">Nom</label>
               <input id="name" type="text" value="{{u?.nom}}" ngModel="{{u?.nom}}">
            </div>
            <!-- nom:string;
               prenom: string;
               nom_ar:string;
               prenom_ar:string;
               matricule:number;
               age:number;
               description:string;-->
            <div class="form-group b">
               <label for="first-name">Prénom</label>
               <input id="first-name" type="text" ngModel="{{u?.prenom}}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group a">
               <label for="name">الاسم بالعربية</label>
               <input id="name" type="text"  ngModel="{{u?.prenom_ar}}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group b">
               <label for="first-name">اللقب بالعربية</label>
               <input id="first-name" type="text"  ngModel="{{u?.nom_ar}}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group b">
               <label for="first-name">Matricule</label>
               <input id="first-name" type="number"  ngModel="{{u?.matricule}}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="zip">Code postal</label>
               <input id="zip" type="number" ngModel="{{u?.codeP}}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="age">Age</label>
               <input id="age" type="number" ngModel="{{u?.age}}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group email-group">
               <label for="email">Email</label>
               <input id="email" type="email" ngModel="{{u?.email}}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group phone-group">
               <label for="phone">Téléphone (mobile)</label>
               <input id="phone" type="tel" v
                  ngModel="{{u?.numTele}}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="address">Adresse</label>
               <input id="address" type="text" ngModel="{{u?.adresse}}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="city">Ville</label>
               <input id="city" type="text" ngModel="{{u?.ville}}">
            </div>
            <div class="textarea-group">
               <label for="bio">Description</label>
               <textarea id="bio"  ngModel="{{u?.description}}" ></textarea>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="button-container">
            <button class="button" (click)="Modifier(u)">Enregister les modifications</button>
         </div>
      </form>
   </div>
</body>
```

this is my Utilisateur.ts

```
export class Utilisateur
{
  nom:string;
  prenom: string;
  nom_ar:string;
  prenom_ar:string;
  matricule:number;
  age:number;
  description:string;
  email:string
  codeP:string
  numTele:string
  adresse:string
  ville:string
  Grp_membre:string
  constructor(){}
}
```

and this is person.service.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Group } from './group';
import { Utilisateur } from './Utilisateur';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PersonService {

    constructor(private http :HttpClient) { }
    
    public getAllEmp():Observable <Utilisateur[]>
    {
        return this.http.get<Utilisateur[]>('http://localhost:8084/person');
    }
    
    public updateEmp(utilisateur :Utilisateur):Observable <Utilisateur>
    {
        return this.http.put <Utilisateur>('http://localhost:8084/edit',utilisateur);
    }
    
    public addEmp(utilisateur:Utilisateur):Observable<Utilisateur>
    {
      return this.http.post<Utilisateur>('http://localhost:8084/addEmp',utilisateur);
    }
    
    public findEmpBy (id: number)
    {
        return this.http.get<Utilisateur>(`http://localhost:8084/edit/${id}`)
    }
    
    public getAllGrp():Observable <Group[]>
    {
        return this.http.get<Group[]>('http://localhost:8084/group');
    }
    
    
    public DeleteEmp(matricule:number):Observable <Utilisateur>
    {
        return this.http.delete<Utilisateur>(`http://localhost:8084/deleteEmp/${matricule}`);
    }
}
```

[image: this is the form output]

Comment: Try changing `value="{{u?.nom}}" ngModel="{{u?.nom}}"`  to  `[(ngModel)]="u?.nom"` and `ngModel="{{u?.prenom}}"`  to  `[(ngModel)]="u?.prenom"`... accordingly make this change for all ngModel

Comment: I do this but it dosen't work and the same error was appeared